# What's the name of this dish (or name of fish) in these pictures?

Tags: fish, food-identification

the following dish calls for Roasted Tomato and Saffron Vinaigrette (also called bouillabaisse?). My cookbook says they're excellent for fish dishes. Do you know what's the name of the fish (or dish) in the following pictures? I'm trying to recreate what's in my cookbook. Thank you for your help!

the Roasted Tomato and Saffron Vinaigrette has: mustard, shallot(minced), garlic(minced), red wine vinegar, thyme (chopped), orange juice, orange zest, red pepper flakes, saffron, tomatoes (chopped and roasted), mild French olive oil, salt, patis

[image: fish1]
[image: fish2]
[image: fish3]
[image: fish4]

Answer (score 2):

Bouillabaisse is a traditional fish stew originating in the French port city of Marseille.  While the sauce in your recipe might have some ingredients in common with that dish, it is not a bouillabaisse.  Pictured is a firm, white fish.  I'm not sure I can identify the exact species, but it might be halibut or cod.  Given the sauce and the plating, I would say any firm, white fish would work in the recipe.

Comment: moscafj, thank you for your answer. It's helpful! Do you know how should I cook the white fish? I'm thinking of sprinkling it with salt then bake it in the oven. When the fish is cooked, I'm pour the Roasted Tomato and Saffron Vinaigrette on top of it.

Comment: That would work.

Answer (score 1):

The use of saffron makes me think the recipe author has taken inspiration from a [Rouille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouille) which is a sauce typically served with bouillabaisse.